# Find a composite of function that is not continuous on its domain.

Tags: real-analysis

Find $f(x)$ such that $f(x)$ is continuous on $\mathbb{R}\backslash\mathbb{Q}$, but not on $\mathbb{Q}$. Then find a function $g(x)$ that is discontinuous at only one point and $(f \circ g)(x)$ is not continuous anywhere.

I know that one possibility for $f(x)$ is the modified Thomae's function, e.g.
$f(x) = 1/q$ if $x=p/q \in \mathbb{Q}$ where $p, q>0$ are relatively prime, and $f(x) = 0$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $f(x) = 1$ if $x=0$.

But I am having some trouble finding a function $g$ that works for the second condition.

Comment: Your definition of Thomae's function is careless $-$ there are at least two mistakes.

Comment: @TonyK I was looking at https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/intro_analysis_pdf/ch7.pdf for the definition. But I agree that it is careless on my part.

Comment: You should say "one candidate for f is Thomae's function", not that it must be Thomae's function. I think you should edit the question with TonyK's comment in mind. Also tell us what the domain of g is, etc. And should it be $g\circ f$?

Comment: @zhw. Since the question does not classify what the domain of $g$ is, I think we can choose whatever works. Further, $f \circ g$ is the correct order.

Comment: Actually Thomae's function is continuous at $0.$ So is $f$ continuous at $0$ or not?

Comment: I modified it a little. We can always set the domain of $f$ to be $(0,1]$.

Comment: Do you mean $g \circ f$ instead of $f \circ g$? If so you could send $x \leq 0$ to $1$ and everything else to $0$ to get the Dirichlet function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you mean $g \circ f$ instead of $f \circ g$.

Suppose such a $g$ existed such that $f \circ g$ was discontinuous everywhere. Suppose $g$ is continuous away from $x$. Then if $g$ contained any irrational in $z \in g(\mathbb{R} \setminus \{x\})$ we have $g(y) = z$. Then since $g$ is continuous at $y$ and $f$ is continous at $g(y)$ we have $f \circ g$ is continuous at $y$, a contradiction. This implies that $g$ only hits the rationals on $ \mathbb{R} \setminus \{ x\}$, but by intermediate value theorem we have $g$ must be constant on $(- \infty, x)$ and $(x, \infty)$. $f \circ g$ is constant on these intervals (and therefore continuous).

Thus no such $g$ exists. Instead if we look at $g \circ f$ we can define $g(x) = 0$ if $x > 0$ and $g(x) = 1$ if $x \leq 0$. Then we have $g\circ f = 0$ if $x \in \mathbb{Q}$ and $g\circ f =1$ if $x \not\in \mathbb{Q}$. This is the dirichlet function, and is known to not be continuous anywhere.